# How can I fix code for a simple array. I created a constructor by using key word:new I run code and get: ReferenceError: Products not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm working out of a text book JavaScript All-In_One. I'm following the directions to write an array. I'm using vscode. This is my array:

```js
const list = new Products['eggs','milk','cheese','garlic','onion','kale','salt','pepper'];
```

When I run visual studio I get the error. Products not defined.

I tried declaring the array before assigning it. When I run the code I expect to get the list in the array. When I write Products.length I expect to get the length of the array characters. I tried using the console in the browser and I get the same error.

Comment: Please provide the `Products` constructor definition

Comment: not likely the book contains syntax errors, so read the book carefully and compare what you have typed, what you show us is invalid JavaScript

Comment: you don't run the code with VSC, you run JS with NodeJS or in a Web browser

Comment: if you show a code fragment show a complete runnable snippet, if I run your code I also get `Products not defined`, you talk about creating a constructor: **show us that constructor**

Answer (score 0):

If the `Products` constructor accepts an array argument:

```js
const list = new Products(['eggs','milk','cheese','garlic','onion','kale','salt','pepper']);
```

The syntax for instantiating a class is:
`new <class_name>(arg1, arg2, ...);`

Comment: I found the solution in w3school and deleted the questions yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were trying to do:

```js
const Products = new Array('eggs','milk','cheese','garlic','onion','kale','salt','pepper'); 
console.log(Products.length,Products)
// or ...
const Products2=['eggs','milk','cheese','garlic','onion','kale','salt','pepper']; 
console.log(Products2.length,Products2);
```